# How Do I Convert This LinqToTwitter query from Console results to View results in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-twitter

Im a rookie and could use some help.

I was looking at examples of LinqToTwitter and am trying to figure out how to display the results in my view instead of the console.

```
var srch =
   (from search in twitterCtx.Search
    where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
    search.Query == "LINQ to Twitter" &&
    search.Count == 7
    select search).SingleOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery: {0}\n", srch.SearchMetaData.Query);
    srch.Statuses.ForEach(entry =>
        Console.WriteLine(
           "ID: {0, -15}, Source: {1}\nContent: {2}\n",
            entry.StatusID, entry.Source, entry.Text));
```

I would like to use a ViewModel if possible.

Thank you!

-Update-

Thanks Joe. Here's where I am after your help. I'm stuck at the part where I need to store the results into my viewmodel. I appreciate any help given. Thanks!

### Controller

```
twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

List<TweetViewModel> TwitterResults = 
(
    from search in twitterCtx.Search
    where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
    search.ResultType == ResultType.Recent &&
    search.Query == "killsometime" &&
    search.Count == 10
    select new TweetViewModel
    {
        ScreenName = search.Statuses. >> "I'm Stuck Here",
        Text = search.Statuses. >> "I'm Stuck Here"
    }
 ).ToList();

    return View(TwitterResults);
```

### ViewModel

```
public class TweetViewModel
{
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<FVV.ViewModels.TweetViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<ul>
@foreach (var tweet in Model)
{
    <li>ScreenName: @tweet.ScreenName, Tweet: @tweet.Text</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ASP.NET MVC samples on the [LINQ to Twitter Samples](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Samples&referringTitle=Home) page. The demos might be a little dated, but will probably easy to tweak if there are any problems. You'll probably want to update the NuGet package.

Also, the downloadable source code contains a LinqToTwitterMvcDemo that does a query and loads a collection of TweetViewModel into a view. It isn't part of the solution, but you can right-click on the Solution, select Add, Existing Project, and navigate to the LinqToTwitterMvcDemo folder under the LinqToTwitter folder to find it. Just add your credentials in Web.config and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Joe. I edited my question with my latest code. Im stuck at storing the results into my viewmodel. Im not sure what I should put at ScreenName = search.Statuses.???

Comment: It's better to break it into two steps. 1) Materialize the search with LINQ to Twitter. 2) Project on srch.Statuses with LINQ to Objects. Pseudocode: var srch = (from search in ctx.Search where search.Type == SearchTypeSearch && search.Query == "..." select search).SingleOrDefault(); List<TweetViewModel> tweets = (from tweet in srch.Statuses select new TweetViewModel { ... }).ToList(); View(tweets);

Comment: Bingo! Thank you so much for all your help and an awesome library!